# Saving an image from a URL that does not end with image extension

Tags: python, image, python-requests, urllib

I'm a python beginner. I have a dataset column that contains thousands of URLs. I want to save the image in each URL with its extension. I don't have a problem with urls that end with the image extension like https://web.archive.org/web/20170628093753im_/http://politicot.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Sean-Spicer.jpg.(with urllib or requests)
However for URLs like link1= https://nypost.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2017/11/171106-texas-shooter-church-index.jpg?quality=90&strip=all&w=1200 or link2 = https://i2.wp.com/www.huzlers.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/maxresdefault.jpeg?fit=1280%2C720&ssl=1, i failed to save them.
I want to save the images in links as follows: image1.jpg and image2.jpeg. How can we do this?
Any help could be useful.

Comment: You could try splitting the string on the `?` symbol and retain the first split as URL.

Comment: Please provide the code example that you'd like to have feedback on.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following seems to work for me, give it a try:

```
import requests
urls = ['https://nypost.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2017/11/171106-texas-shooter-church-index.jpg?quality=90&strip=all&w=1200',
        'https://i2.wp.com/www.huzlers.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/maxresdefault.jpeg?fit=1280%2C720&ssl=1']

for i, url in enumerate(urls):
    r = requests.get(url)
    filename = 'image{0}.jpg'.format(i+1)

    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Maybe I wasn't clear enough but it works for jpg links, the problem is that I also have other links like png or ico, for example: https://web.archive.org/web/20180117041602im_/https://i0.wp.com/theuspoliticalnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Screen-Shot-2018-01-13-at-1.39.11-PM.png?fit=614%2C343.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a valid url of an image.

Comment: @PApostol thanks for the suggestion this method. I am trying other urls and it works for me but unfortunate the format in jpg and png seems not working in my machine. I m not that sure why it happened like that